# Does lavender repel moths?

Tags: biology, zoology, household

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavandula#Other_uses), it is said that

> Dried and sealed in pouches, lavender flowers are placed among stored items of clothing to give a fresh fragrance and to deter moths.

I know many people do it. Has this been tested to actually deter the moths? How effective is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the US Department of Agriculture, [Bulletin 707: Results of Experiments with miscellaneous substances against bedbugs, cockroaches, clothes moths, and carpet beetles.](https://books.google.com/books?id=9P1eaMIkWrEC&pg=PA26&dq=lavender%20moths&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM7JWL59LLAhUmsoMKHXfOCoYQ6AEINDAB#v=onepage&q=lavender%20moths&f=false):

> *Effect on clothes-moth adults*. — Lavender flowers, cayenne pepper, and allspice are of no value in preventing moth infestation.
>   Cloves and oil of lavender were effective in protecting flannel from moth infestation.

Comment: The source is nearly a hundred years old :D I guess not much has changed since then.